# Teste de Unidade Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, testes-de-unidade, entity-framework-core

Olá, estou começando um projeto e é a primeira vez que trabalho com teste de unidade, estamos tentando realizar o  teste de unidade no EF Core, so que ao testar o Get, nao estou conseguindo pegar o valor de _empresaService, segue o codigo de teste, fiz uma injeção de dependencia e acho que é por isso que nao estou conseguindo.

```
public class EmpresaTest
    {
        private readonly IEmpresaService _empresaService;

        public EmpresaTest()
        {
            var service = new ServiceCollection();
            service.AddDbContext<VetorPDVContext>((s, o) => o.UseInMemoryDatabase("pdvDI").EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
            service.AddScoped<VetorPDVContext, VetorPDVContext>();
            service.AddTransient<IEmpresaRepository, EmpresaRepository>();
            service.AddTransient<IEmpresaService, EmpresaService>();
            service.AddTransient<IEmpresaAppService, EmpresaAppService>();

            var provider = service.BuildServiceProvider();
            _empresaService = provider.GetService<IEmpresaService>();

            

            InitContext();
        }

        public void InitContext()
        {
            var controller = new EmpresaAppService(_empresaService);
            var empresa = new EmpresaModel { CodigoEmpresa = 1, CgcEmpresa = "00000000/0000-00", RazaoSocial = "Empresa 01", NomeFantasia = "Empresa 01" };
            controller.Add(empresa);
        }
        [Fact]
        public void TestGetAsync()
        {
           var result = _empresaService.Get(emp => emp.CodigoEmpresa == 1).Result.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O que ocorre é que você parece estar indo efetivamente ao banco, o que não faz sentido, o teste deve ser feito ao que refere-se ao método.
Caso não conheça, sugiro que faça um mock do serviço, desta forma você manipula os resultados esperados dos testes para qualquer parte do seu serviço.
Costumo usar o Moq, existe muito material disponível sobre ele.

[Nuget Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/)